# Cursor is only returning one value, not all values

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  I want to retrieve all values of a column, but I am only getting one of the values.  I have tried everything, but I could still not find a solution.  Here is my code in my database:

```
 public Cursor returnAllColumns() {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE,
            new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME,
            KEY_CUSTOMER, PROTEIN, TOTAL_CARB}
            , null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
}
    return cursor;
}
```

Here is my code in another class where it shows a toast with all the values.

```
mDbHelper = new DBAdapter(DatabaseFiller.this);
                    mDbHelper.open();
                    Cursor c = mDbHelper.returnAllColumns();

                    String protein = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("protein"));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), protein, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

All I am getting is `Protein = 0`.  What I should be getting is `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...`.  I don't know what I am doing wrong here.  In my ListView, I got it right.  It worked perfectly there.  Here is my ListView code:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("customer"));
                String caloriescursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                String totalfat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                String satfatcursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("city"));
                String state = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("state"));
                String zipCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("zipCode"));
```

And that returns a Toast with a bunch of values.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getAllColumns()`, your query statement is correct. It does in fact fetch all columns. The `if` statement that follows simply points it to the first result. Then you are returning the cursor while it is pointed to the first result. You should take out the `if` statement because it doesn't do anything useful.

When trying to show the toast, you want something like this:

```
Cursor c = mDbHelper.returnAllColumns();
ArrayList<String> protein = new ArrayList<>();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    protein.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("protein")));
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TextUtils.join(", ", protein), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the cursor if the cursor is returning more than one row, and build your output in the loop.

Keep calling `c.moveToNext()` until it returns false.

Comment: Hey, I am a beginner in Android.  Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I did this:

```
if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "=== cursor not moveToFirst() ===");

    return null;
}

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "=== reading cursor of getAll() ===");
Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(cursor));

List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    trips.add(cursorToTrip(cursor));

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

The `cursor.moveToNext()` will never check the first element. So I check in the course is not in the last one and then I add the object and move to the next one.

That's it! :)